# Javascript not working in IE, fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, onclick

Here's the code - it's really elementary, and I can't think of what's going wrong  It gives an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error in IE when the small images with the "onclick" code is clicked.  It works fine in Firefox!  Please help!

```
<script language="javascript">
    function showproduct1() 
    {
        document.getelementbyid("productimg").src = "../images/productimg1.jpg";  
    }

    function showproduct2()
    {
        document.getelementbyid("productimg").src = "../images/productimg2.jpg";  
    }    
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)"  title="Product 1">
    <img src="../images/productimg1.jpg" style="height: 60px" onclick="showproduct1()" />
</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"  title="Product 2">
    <img src="../images/productimg2.jpg" style="height: 60px" onclick="showproduct2()" />
</a>

<a href="../images/productimg1.jpg" target="_blank" title="Click on Image to Expand">
    <img src="../images/productimg1.jpg" width="210" border="0" alt="Product" id="productimg">
</a><br>

<br><small><strong>Click on images to expand</strong></small><p><strong>
```

Comment: Does this really work on Firefox ?

Comment: You should study more on writing valid JS.

Comment: Does this work in FiReFoX? :)

Comment: This code does not work in Fx through jsFiddle.

Answer (score 7):

Case matters:

```
document.getelementbyid
```

should be ...

```
document.getElementById
```

**Update: I can confirm that the first example does not work in the latest version (21.0) of Fx.**

Comment: I'm a little surprised this works in Firefox, in a way. I'm not sure it's a good idea to allow lazy coding that's going to break in other browsers.

Comment: @Katana314 My test of that syntax in Fx (on JSFiddle) failed. I have not tried it outside of that context though.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case-sensitive language.

It should be `getElementById` not `getelementbyid`